# Android13 Permission denied while picking images

Tags: android, flutter, image

[image][image]after android13 release my application got a problem with picking image it show permission denied while picking image.

On androidMinifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

Flutter 1.17

Image_picker:
multiple_image_picker:

Error capture image is above.

[image]

Comment: did you tried clearing cache & data or uninstalling completely and reinstalling? Also tried another device?

Comment: Yep I have been clear cache & data also have been test with device more than one.

Comment: Try this package and see if the issue still persists. [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)

Comment: did you added the runtime permission in activity or fragment or dart file?

Comment: Which permission is denied?

Comment: Not sure which permission denied just know while pick image from library.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried 2 packages like [multi_image_picker](https://multi_image_picker:%20%5E4.8.1) and [multiple_images_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/multiple_images_picker/changelog), the result is that the two packages don't support Android 13+ yet. So i replaced it with [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) and it worked.

```
await ImagePicker().pickMultiImage();
```

You can see in this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-image_picker-in-flutter/) for tutorial